# Sharedpreference only saves latest string after app restart

Tags: android

I am currently trying to save chatnames locally but only the latest preference is saved. Below is how I'm saving the string to a specific key.

```
public void saveSettings(Context context, String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value).apply();
```

This is how I retrieve the string:

```
public String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key,defaultValue);
}
```

The problem is that it will only return the last saved string, rest of the keys will return `defaultvalue`. E.g I'm saving 3 different strings with 3 different keys with the first method. When trying to retrieve the strings with `getString()`
It will only return the string for the last saved key.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the preference file and check if the data is being written?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am wrong but , i can't see a commit here , on editor...

Comment: I am using apply which is doing the same thing as commit if I've understood it correctly

Comment: Yeap, i guess , just give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The way you formally save preferences is using the `commit()` method, like the following:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I am using apply which is doing the same thing as commit if I've understood it correctly

Comment: @CT.Kevin the difference between the two is that .commit() is persistent (i.e. it stores preferences to permanent storage). The .apply() only creates the change in memory, so restarting the app doesn't keep those preferences.

Comment: @CT.Kevin also want to point out that, yes, apply does write to storage asyncronously, but if there's some issue preventing that, you won't get notified, so there may be a deeper issue with what you're doing than is apparent, and you should be able to debug.

Comment: I changed it to commit but the problem still exist, only the last saved string remains after restarting the application.

Comment: @CT.Kevin have you tried getting the preferences in the following way, rather than through PreferenceManager?      "SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);"

Comment: Yes, it did not work. I'll come back to this problem later with a fresh mindset... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @CT.Kevin Sorry about that, good luck figuring out the issue.